# Can webpack report which file triggered a compilation in watch mode?

Tags: file, logging, build, webpack, watch

I would like for Webpack to log which file triggered my watch mode build.

I have configured a plugin that listens to the `watch-run` compiler event hook like this:

```
function() {
  this.plugin("watch-run", function(watching, callback) {
    // maybe something in `watching` will indicate the changed file?
    // when I find out what it is, `console.log` it here
    callback();
  });
}

// Example output: "/Users/aaron/git/test/index.js" was changed, new build triggered
```

But I cannot figure out where the changed file information might be, if it is there at all.

The Webpack documentation is really lacking in this area. The [Compiler Event Hook](https://webpack.js.org/api/plugins/compiler/) page doesn't have any examples (only a message to explain that examples are coming soon), and the [old v1 documentation](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html#the-compilation-instance) is not much better at elaborating the properties/methods available in the `watching`/`compiler` object.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This kind of information is not covered by the webpack documentation and it would be difficult to include every possible option that is available on the compiler. But I would say that this is an area where you should explore the available options by either reading the source code or spinning up a debugger and investigate them. I did the latter and found that the changed files are available in:

```
watching.compiler.watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes
```

This is an object where each key is an absolute path to a file that has been changed and the value is the timestamp when it has been changed. It is possible to have more than one file change that triggers the recompilation, when multiple changes have been saved within the configured poll interval.

The following code prints the files that have been changed (the files might also be empty):

```
this.plugin("watch-run", (watching, done) => {
  const changedTimes = watching.compiler.watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes;
  const changedFiles = Object.keys(changedTimes)
    .map(file => `\n  ${file}`)
    .join("");
  if (changedFiles.length) {
    console.log("New build triggered, files changed:", changedFiles);
  }
  done();
});
```

An example output of this is:

```
New build triggered, files changed:
  /path/to/app/src/components/item/Item.js
  /path/to/app/src/App.js
```

Note: This output will come before the final stats are printed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information... Your code allowed me to find out the reason for non-stop continuous HMR rebuild in my project caused by a stray .html file created by code coverage module.

Answer (score 37):

For Webpack 5, since `watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes` [has been removed](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/4106), I've changed the [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140501/can-webpack-report-which-file-triggered-a-compilation-in-watch-mode/55139759#55139759) by [Sander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2013616/sander) to this:

```js
class WatchRunPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('WatchRun', (comp) => {
            if (comp.modifiedFiles) {
                const changedFiles = Array.from(comp.modifiedFiles, (file) => `\n  ${file}`).join('');
                console.log('===============================');
                console.log('FILES CHANGED:', changedFiles);
                console.log('===============================');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `console.log()` can output mid-line inside other log output. You can get a webpack logger with: `const logger = comp.getInfrastructureLogger('WatchRun');` and then use `logger.log()`

Answer (score 31):

The plugin I used for this in Webpack 4:

```
class WatchRunPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('WatchRun', (comp) => {
      const changedTimes = comp.watchFileSystem.watcher.mtimes;
      const changedFiles = Object.keys(changedTimes)
        .map(file => `\n  ${file}`)
        .join('');
      if (changedFiles.length) {
        console.log("====================================")
        console.log('NEW BUILD FILES CHANGED:', changedFiles);
        console.log("====================================")
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: awesome. I'm using Laravel mix and for some reason i had to add a constructor `constructor() {}` for this to work

Comment: If this isn't working then take a look at the answer below which uses the second argument `done` (or `callback` in the docs). I couldn't get this to work without invoking the callback at the end. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52363168/697745. With the callback it works nicely.

Comment: I just copypasta that at the type of my webpack.config.js file, then add  `new WatchRunPlugin()` to my plugins and... Bob's your uncle.

Comment: If you're using `WatchIgnorePlugin` you need:
`const watcher = comp.watchFileSystem.wfs ? comp.watchFileSystem.wfs.watcher : comp.watchFileSystem.watcher;  const changedTimes = watcher.mtimes;`

Comment: @Sander I'm getting changed filenames which is great, but also sometimes just a timestamp instead of a filename. Ive ignored many of the files, so now Im getting rebuilds triggered for a "file" indicated with a timestamp. So to be clear: Object.keys() returned a timestamp. Any idea why?

Answer (score 10):

In webpack 4 you can access to `watcher` in that way:

```
getChangedFiles(compiler) {
  const { watchFileSystem } = compiler;
  const watcher = watchFileSystem.watcher || watchFileSystem.wfs.watcher;

  return Object.keys(watcher.mtimes);
}
```

latter in watchRun hook

```
compiler.hooks.watchRun.tapAsync('plugin name', (_compiler, done) => {
  const changedFile = this.getChangedFiles(_compiler)

  // ...

  return done();
});
```