# webpack watch mode with CopyWebpackPlugin causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, webpack

In webpack, **CopyWebpackPlugin** causes infinite loop when webpack is in watch mode. I tried to add **watchOptions.ignored** option but it doesn't seem to work. 
My webpack config is following:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {

    entry: {
        'res': './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].min.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production') 
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'dist', to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs/js') }
        ], {})
    ],

    watchOptions: {
        ignored: path.resolve(__dirname, 'docs/js')
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So I know this question is very old at this point, but I was running into this endless loop issue again recently and found a couple of solutions.

1. Not the cleanest method, but if you add an "assets" folder, which can be completely empty, to the root of your project, it seems to only compile after your sources folder changes.
2. The better method I have found is within the webpack config.  The original poster mentioned about using ignored which does seem to fix the issue if you instruct webpack to watch file changes after the initial build and to ignore your dist/output folder...

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  watch: true,
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: ['**/dist/**', '**/node_modules'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same problem.

I first tried the solution below with the `wathOptions.ignored` setting in the root of the webpack config.

```
watchOptions: {
    ignored: ['**/node_modules'],
}
```

This however felt like a "nuclear" solution.
With some extra investigation I found a more clean fix for this:

1. create a webpack plugin to print the modified files which are the trigger for the watch to trigger, this code originates from the stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64564708:

   ```
   class WatchRunPlugin {
       apply(compiler) {
           compiler.hooks.watchRun.tap('WatchRun', (comp) => {
               if (comp.modifiedFiles) {
                   const changedFiles = Array.from(comp.modifiedFiles, (file) => `\n  ${file}`).join('');
                   console.log('===============================');
                   console.log('FILES CHANGED:', changedFiles);
                   console.log('===============================');
               }
           });
       }
   }
   ```
2. use this plugin in your webpack config, add it to the list of plugins
3. start a build watch and reproduce the infinite loop
4. look at the FILES CHANGED message to identify the files causing the infinite loop
5. fix this issue: for me, these were files originating from an npm package in the node_modules folder, these were added to the CopyWebpackPlugin with a glob pattern (*). By replacing the glob pattern by the actual file names, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

With CopyWebpackPlugin, I've experienced the infinite loop too. I tried all kinds of CopyWebpackPlugin configurations with no luck yet. After hours of wasted time I found I could hook into the compiler and fire off my own copy method.

**Running Watch**

I'm using webpack watch to watch for changes. In the package.json, I use this config so I can run `npm run webpackdev`, and it will watch for file changes.

```
"webpackdev": "cross-env webpack --env.environment=development --env.basehref=/ --watch"
```

**My Workaround**

I've added an inline plugin with a compiler hook, which taps into AfterEmitPlugin. This allows me to copy after my sources have been generated after the compile. This method works great to copy my npm build output to my maven target webapp folder.

```
// Inline custom plugin - will copy to the target web app folder
// 1. Run npm install fs-extra
// 2. Add fix the path, so that it copies to the server's build webapp folder
{
  apply: (compiler) => {
    compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
      // Debugging
      console.log("########-------------->>>>> Finished Ext JS Compile <<<<<------------#######");

      let source = __dirname + '/build/';
      // TODO Set the path to your webapp build
      let destination = __dirname + '/../dash-metrics-server/target/metrics-dash';

      let options = {
        overwrite: true
      };
      fs.copy(source, destination, options, err => {
        if (err) return console.error(err) {
            console.log('Copy build success!');
        }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

**The Workaround Source**

Here's my webpack.config.js in total for more context. (In this webpack configuration, I'm using Sencha's Ext JS ExtWebComponents as the basis.)

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');
const ExtWebpackPlugin = require('@sencha/ext-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

module.exports = function(env) {
    function get(it, val) {if(env == undefined) {return val;} else if(env[it] == undefined) {return val;} else {return env[it];}}

    var profile = get('profile', '');
    var emit = get('emit', 'yes');
    var environment = get('environment', 'development');
    var treeshake = get('treeshake', 'no');
    var browser = 'no'; // get('browser', 'no');
    var watch = get('watch', 'yes');
    var verbose = get('verbose', 'no');
    var basehref = get('basehref', '/');
    var build_v = get('build_v', '7.0.0.0');

    const isProd = environment === 'production';
    const outputFolder = 'build';

    const plugins = [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({template: 'index.html', hash: false, inject: 'body'}),

        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: basehref }),

        new ExtWebpackPlugin({
          framework: 'web-components',
          toolkit: 'modern',
          theme: 'theme-material',
          emit: emit,
          script: './extract-code.js',
          port: 8080,
          packages: [
              'renderercell',
              'font-ext',
              'ux',
              'd3',
              'pivot-d3',
              'font-awesome',
              'exporter',
              'pivot',
              'calendar',
              'charts',
              'treegrid',
              'froala-editor'
          ],
          profile: profile,
          environment: environment,
          treeshake: treeshake,
          browser: browser,
          watch: watch,
          verbose: verbose,
          inject: 'yes',
          intellishake: 'no'
        }),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: '../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js',
            to: './webcomponents-bundle.js'
        }]),

        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: '../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js.map',
            to: './webcomponents-bundle.js.map'
        }]),

        // Debug purposes only, injected via script: npm run-script buildexample -- --env.build_v=<full version here in format maj.min.patch.build>
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            BUILD_VERSION: JSON.stringify(build_v)
        }),

        // This causes infinite loop, so I can't use this plugin.
        //  new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
        //    from: __dirname + '/build/',
        //    to: __dirname + '/../dash-metrics-server/target/test1'
        //  }]),

        // Inline custom plugin - will copy to the target web app folder
        // 1. Run npm install fs-extra
        // 2. Add fix the path, so that it copies to the server's build webapp folder
        {
          apply: (compiler) => {
            compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', (compilation) => {
              // Debugging
              console.log("########-------------->>>>> Finished Ext JS Compile <<<<<------------#######");

              let source = __dirname + '/build/';
              // TODO Set the path to your webapp build
              let destination = __dirname + '/../dash-metrics-server/target/metrics-dash';

              let options = {
                overwrite: true
              };
              fs.copy(source, destination, options, err => {
                if (err) return console.error(err)

                console.log('Copy build success!');

              })
            });
          }
        }

    ];
    return {
        mode: environment,
        devtool: (environment === 'development') ? 'inline-source-map' : false,
        context: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
        //entry: './index.js',
        entry: {
        //    ewc:  './ewc.js',
            app: './index.js'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, outputFolder),
            filename: '[name].js'
        },


        plugins: plugins,
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(js)$/, exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'babel-loader',
                        // 'eslint-loader'
                    ]
                },
                { test: /\.(html)$/, use: { loader: 'html-loader' } },
                {
                    test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                    use: [
                        { loader: 'style-loader' },
                        { loader: 'css-loader' },
                        { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        performance: { hints: false },
        stats: 'none',
        optimization: { noEmitOnErrors: true },
        node: false
    };
};
```