# webpack --watch is not ignoring files

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

The main problem is that when watch detects a change in a source file and re-compiles, it gets stuck into a loop because it has updated the `index.php` page where I insert the compiled javascript into the  element (through HtmlWebpackPlugin). I've tried ignoring everything (in `watchOptions` in my config file) in my `build_app` directory where the index.php file lives, as well as explicitly ignoring that file, and it still seems to get stuck in this rebuilding loop because it detects changes in that file.

I've tried using the [TimeFixPlugin](https://github.com/egoist/time-fix-plugin) which seemed to help some people, and I'm using this [WatchRunPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55139759/2520534) someone created in another StackOverflow question to debug which files have been detected as changed by `webpack --watch`, but it doesn't seem to help.

output when --watch detects my first changed file (notice that when compilation finishes, it detects another change in `index.php` when the new .js script is added to the index page through HtmlWebpackPlugin:

```
====================================
NEW BUILD FILES CHANGED: 
  /Users/blah/project1/src/common/services/AuthService/AuthService.class.js
====================================

Compilation  starting…


Compilation  finished

Hash: b90fb62dff8c1a7732e0
Version: webpack 4.42.0
Time: 375ms
Built at: 03/26/2020 1:47:11 PM
                                             Asset      Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
assets/js/app.b90fb62dff8c1a7732e0.js   736 KiB     app  [emitted] [immutable]  app
                                         index.php  76.6 KiB          [emitted]              
 + 1 hidden asset
Entrypoint app = assets/js/vendors.6828eff62e21c38585ce.js assets/js/app.b90fb62dff8c1a7732e0.js
[./src/common/services/AuthService/AuthService.class.js] 9.76 KiB {app} [built]
    + 36 hidden modules
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.php":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.php
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./build_app/index.php] 77.9 KiB {1} [built]
        + 3 hidden modules
====================================
NEW BUILD FILES CHANGED: 
  /Users/blah/project1/build_app/index.php
====================================
```

webpack.config.js (located in `/Users/blah/project1`, the same directory I'm running the webpack command from):

```
mode: 'development',
plugins: [
    new TimeFixPlugin(),
    new WatchRunPlugin(),

    // Clean build_app folder
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['build_app_webpack'], {
        // Write logs to console.
        verbose: true,

        // perform clean just before files are emitted to the output dir
        // Default: false
        beforeEmit: true
    }),

    // Create our index.php file
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './build_app/index.php',
        filename: 'index.php',
        inject: 'head',          // place scripts in head because we bootstrap the app at the end of the body
        hash: true,                  // cache busting helper
        templateParameters: {
            LR_VERSION: gitRevisionPlugin.version(),
            LR_HASH: gitRevisionPlugin.commithash()
        }
    }),

    // Expose _ (underscoreJS) to the global JavaScript scope
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        _: 'underscore'
    })
],
watchOptions: {
    ignored: [
        'bin_*/**',
        'build_*/**',
        'build_app/index.php',
        'karma/html-output/**',
        'jest/coverage/**',
        'jest/test-results/**',
        'node_modules/**',
        'vendor/**'
    ]
}
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this was partially due to the fact that I'm currently transitioning between Grunt and Webpack, so I had to have the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` looking at a template and outputting the resulting `index.php` file in the same directory (which happened to be the same directory as my webpack `output.path` in the config). Additionally, I hadn't realized it yet, but this was also causing the new compiled scripts to be added to the index.php page without removing the previous ones.

Still not sure why it wasn't ignoring the file that I explicitly told it to ignore, but I fixed the issue by changing my old Grunt config to build the index file into a `build_app_tmp` directory instead of the final `build_app` directory (i.e. the webpack output direcotry), and then I configured `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to use the `build_app_tmp` directory to find the template.

This also allows me to watch the `build_app_tmp` directory for any changes to the `index.php` file that Grunt may have made.

Comment: Similar to my issue, too.

I was making a switch from react to another framework and was bombarded by hundreds of EMFILE errors for the `node_modules` directory.

I needed to `rm -fr node_modules package-lock.json bin build` (all of those), then do a reinstall with `npm i --include=dev`.