# React and Prettier/eslint app looping run script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

My Create React App is compiling over and over. Aside the fact is shouldn't do that its also very distracting.

this is the output from the default `npm run start`

I'm guessing it's something to do with linting, ideas?

[image]

EDIT:

scripts requested:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint:check": "eslint . --max-warnings=0",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix --max-warnings=0",
    "prettier:check": "prettier . --check",
    "prettier:fix": "prettier . --write"
  }
```

EDIT 2:
I have now removed all eslint packages from the project and deleted the prettier and eslint files and the app still behaves as shown in the GIF attached to this

---

EDIT 3:

For anyone who sees this, it still isn't solved.

- removed linting completely
- redone all my typescript types and interfaces making sure they're correctly referenced etc...
- tried it on Mac, Windows, Linux all of them do the same thing.
- Launched the app outside of an IDE using Powershell and zsh they do the same thing
- updated all my packages
- got a fresh tsconfig file
- removed node_modules
- tried yarn an npm both of them do the same

I'm at a loss here, the comments and answers are all helpful but non of them solve the issue.

Comment: Show scripts from package.json

Comment: added to question, however as I said its the default

Comment: After deleting the packages, I hope you did a fresh npm start to check if the issue still persists. If you've already done this, then try and work backwards to figure out what changes you made to the project to cause it behave this way.

Comment: Try using depcheck - https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck - might have some circular dependencies going on?

Comment: Try to remove node modules folder and then do `npm install` and then `npm start` again.

Comment: Is it doing this when you run 'npm start' or when you actually change and save something in the code? May be the issue is with react or webpack versions. Try upgrading/downgrading the versions for react and webpack.

Answer (score 2):

there are seveal things that could be happening.

here are some from what I've encountered in the past:

1. There is a file that keeps changing on you. maybe you IDE is opened and for some reason is saving the file, or a script is updating it, or for some other reason it's being updated and thus reinitiates the compilation.
2. Cache might be messing things up. Try running `npm start -- --reset-cache`. Clearing the cache might be helpful.
3. Switchup the environment. i.e. setup the project on a clear&fresh virutal machine.
4. Disable linting & prettier temporarily. Remove all `eslint` and `prettier` commands from package.json and rerun the project.

Comment: I've disabled linting and prettier in my vs code: no luck. 
tried the npm cache reset: no luck.
tried swithcing to yarn: no luck.
tried running it on my mac (I've been deving on widows for this): no luck but I noticed it takes forever to compile the app, I'm talking like over 2 mins.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that there's a file somewhere in your project directory that gets updated continually. webpack detects the updates and rebuilds your project each time.

Here are some ways to test this theory:

1. Download a file watcher application and point it at your project directory to see if/which files are being modified.
2. Instead of loading your app with `react-scripts start`, create a minimal `webpack.config.js` (or [copy the default one](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/d960b9e38c062584ff6cfb1a70e1512509a966e7/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js) from `react-scripts`) and run your project with `webpack serve` as your start script. Use [a plug-in to determine which files are being updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43140501/can-webpack-report-which-file-triggered-a-compilation-in-watch-mode).